# Need help changing variables to integers in 103 columns in Rstudio

Tags: r

having a problem changing 3 variables into 3 specific integers in 103 columns. specifically: DESPAIR -> =, MEH -> 1, and JOY -> 2. have tried using case_when but does not seem to work. have encountered problems with the NA values and tried to overcome this by making them into 0 as well. but I want to remove the entire row altogether.

i have 2460 rows and 103 columns that i am trying to do use this function. is there a better way or easier way to overcome this problem? I am have also considered using a forloop as well.

> I have tried using the `case_when` function to change the 3 variables into its integer value. but am having a hard time doing that.
>
> Not sure how to provide data, but to give you an idea of the dataframe it is 103 columns x 2460 rows. each row contains either a value of JOY, MEH, or DESPAIR, and a NA Value. **

I am trying to change the JOY, MEH, and DESPAIR values into 2,1, and 0 accordingly, fully delete the NA values entirely by removing the entire row, and keep all the country values.

```
Candy_Hierarchy <- tribble(~COUNTRY, ~candy1, ~candy2, ~candy3
              'United States' ,'JOY', 'DESPAIR', 'MEH',
              'Canada', NA, NA, NA, 
              'United Kingdom', 'MEH', 'JOY', 'DESPAIR')
```

```
Candy_Hierarchy <- case_when(
  Candy_Hierarchy %% DESPAIR ~ 0,
  Candy_Hierarchy %% MEH ~ 1,
  Candy_Hierarchy %% JOY ~ 2,
  TRUE ~ 0
)
```

or

```
for ( col in 2:length(Candy_Hierarchy)) {
DespairVal <- DESPAIR
Candy_Hierarchy$col[Candy_Hierarchy$col %in% DespairVal] <- 0
MehVal <- MEH
Candy_Hierarchy$col[Candy_Hierarchy$col %in% MehVal] <- 1
JoyVal <- JOY
Candy_Hierarchy$col[Candy_Hierarchy$col %in% JoyVal] <- 2
}
```

> not sure if the second works, its just a hypothesis.

when trying the code it receive this error:

> "Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'DESPAIR' not found"

Comment: You could use `df[df == "Joy"] <- 2` etc, and then `as.numeric`, but you are probably better off using factors (depending on how you imported it, your data may already be factors)

Comment: Can you post a dummy data frame with just 2-3 rows and columns? Also, can you confirm that you're using a `data.frame` and not some other tabular object?

Comment: @Rohit Hi Im new to stack overflow. Im not sure how to do that

Comment: @Rohit when i input dput(head(data)) i receive this:

structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)"), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: @FelixChan Please don't post code in the comments. Also, replace `data` with the name of your dataframe.

Comment: @Rohit when i replace data with the name of my dataframe i receive an error

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach

```
library(tidyverse)
Candy_Hierarchy <- tribble(~COUNTRY, ~candy1, ~candy2, ~candy3,
                       'United States' ,'JOY', 'DESPAIR', 'MEH',
                       'Canada', NA, NA, NA, 
                       'United Kingdom', 'MEH', 'JOY', 'DESPAIR')



# Make a function to recode variables
f <- function(x){
  recode(x, 'JOY' = 2, 'MEH' = 1, 'DESPAIR' = 0)}

Candy_Hierachy2 <- Candy_Hierarchy %>% 
  drop_na()  
  # apply recode function to all columns except COUNTRY
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(-COUNTRY), .funs = f)
```

Comment: would the drop_na function also remove rows that have values in them but have one only have one NA in it?

Comment: Hi I realized that the function created also eliminates a column that with different variables that i need to keep. How would i be able to bypass this problem?

Comment: @FelixChan I've edited the answer so recode is not applied to the COUNTRY column

Comment: Thanks, for the help. How would i be able to make it save to the dataframe. as when i open Candy_Hierarchy it no longer has the integers, but reverts back to  "JOY", MEH, and DESPAIR

Comment: @FelixChan We can assign the modified data frame.  See my edit where I've assigned the results to Candy_Hierachy2.  Candy_Hierachy will have the original data.